# Testing a (possibly) bad capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I'm trying to fix a non-working device.  The first thing I'm checking is the capacitors.

I desoldered the biggest one from the board as it seemed to have leaked a bit. It is a 330 μF, 16 V capacitor.

I've tested it with the multimeter and I'm getting a reading of 285 μF.

Does that mean it is bad, or would that reading still be in range given the 330 μF specification?

Comment: It could well be in range; many (most?) electrolitic capacitors are specced with a 20% tolerance. It depends on the specific type and manufacturer. Your reading *by itself* doesn't mean it has gone bad.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was just reading the service manual of this device and for that capacitor it has in fact a 20% tolerance.
Is there any other way I can make sure that the capacitor is good or bad?

Comment: Leakage = I ≦ 0.01 CV or 3 (μA)  is common  but unlikely faulty

Comment: Measure the ESR (equivalent series resistance) of the capacitor. Most multimeters cannot measure this but there are cheap "component testers" on Ebay and Ali for sale that can measure this. Another option is to simply replace **any** capacitor that looks suspicious. Do realize that you replace with the correct type (low ESR or not etc.). Also realize that replacing (all) capacitors might not fix the issue in the end. You might need to do real troubleshooting for that. Look at the repair videos from Dave on the EEVBlog on Youtube.

Comment: Cheap ESR e-caps T= 200us, low ESR towards 2 us so 330uF if 3.3us or 1 mOhms is low ESR 0.1 ohm would be std and a bad low ESR cap which produces lots of ripple Vac

Comment: What is not  working?

Comment: Thanks guys :)
Yes Bimpelrekkie I'll keep troubleshooting the board apart from this capacitor. I'll probably end up replacing all of them as this is quite an old device and it has ~10 electrolytic capacitors
I had this specific question about the measurement of capacitors with the multimeter as I thought that that reading wouldn't mean that the cap is definitely bad but I was not totally sure.

TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 the device doesn't turn on. But I'm just at the beginning of the troubleshooting, so let's see what I find :)

Thank you all!

Comment: A common failure mode for capacitors is that the breakdown voltage reduces; it will work perfectly normally up  to this reduced breakdown voltage and will then start to act as a low impedance.

Comment: If it has leaked, replace it no matter what the measured capacitance is.

Comment: Note that many bigger capacitors are glued to the PCB for mechanical stability.  If you are new to the field, this glue is easy to mistake for "leaking".     Further, when they start to go bad to the point of leaking, they "usually" will also start to bulge a little first.  The tops of bigger caps are designed to pop-out if the pressure inside gets too high.   i.e.  http://www.robotroom.com/Parts/Samsung-monitor-capacitors/Bad-electrolytic-capacitors-with-residue-buldging-and-lift.jpg

Comment: Thanks. I don't think it was glue, a bit of yellow material under the capacitor... but not much. The capacitor is not bulge, that's why I was not so sure that it was bad. And it is a Nichicon which are very good quality. But this device was manufactured on 1984 so I think I will replace all the capacitors.

Comment: @ocrdu please feel free to add your comment as an answer to my question so I can mark it as solved. Your comment was the first one and it actually answered my specific question hehe.
Thank you and thanks everyone for your kind help :)

Comment: @JV-Lobo: OK, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could well be in range; many (most?) electrolitic capacitors are specified with a 20% tolerance; it depends on the specific type and manufacturer.

Your reading *by itself* doesn't mean it has gone bad. You will need other measurements to find out more, but when in doubt, I would just replace it.